# Readline passed a callback on.close execution order

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, asynchronous-javascript

Here I'm using the *Readline* module inside a function that executes a callback function *on.close*. It executes in the expected order (the code *on.close*, then the code in the callback passed to it, this can be seen with the console.log statements), however only part of the final array get's copied (as if part of the code doesn't finish executing in time).

Example output:

```
First: First Thing, 1, Second Thing, 2, Third Thing 3
Second: First Thing, 1
```

How can I get this line of code:

```
console.log("Second: " + result);
```

to execute as with the whole array copied (without moving it all into one function or using async/await)?

```
////////// Required Packages and Initialization //////////
var express = require("express");
var fs = require("fs");
var readline = require("readline");
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/some_folder'));

app.listen(3000);

////////// Request Handler //////////
app.get("/some_request", function(req, res) {
    req.setTimeout(20000);
    input_data = ["First thing", "Second thing", "Third thing"]; // Already in alphabetical order
    file_search(input_data, "a_file.csv", function(output_data) {
        res.json(output_data);
    });
});

////////// Functions //////////
function file_search(name_array, FileName, callback)
{
    csv_fetch_array(name_array, FileName, function(result) {
        console.log("Second: " + result);  // Executes second as expected, but does not contain whole result array, cut short <-----
        callback(result);
    });
}

function csv_fetch_array(name_array, FileName, callback)
{
    var cntr = 0;
    var result = [];
    var len = name_array.length;

    if (!(FileName))
    {
        callback(result);
    }

    var file_stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/some_folder/' + FileName);

    file_stream.on('error', function (err) {
        callback(result);
    });

    var csv_file = readline.createInterface({
        input: file_stream
    });

    // csv file arranged in alphabetical order
    csv_file.on('line', function (line) {
        var search = line.split(",");
        var name_search = search[0];

        ///// Logic to hop to next phrase if past current one alphabetically /////
        if (name_search == name_array[cntr])
        {
            result.push(search);
            if (++cntr >= len)
            {
                csv_file.close();
                csv_file.removeAllListeners(); // Otherwise readline continues to empty buffer
            }
        }
        else if (name_search > name_array[cntr])
        {
            if (++cntr >= len)
            {
                csv_file.close();
                csv_file.removeAllListeners();
            }
            else if(name_search == name_array[cntr])
            {
                result.push(search);
                if (++cntr >= len)
                {
                    csv_file.close();
                    csv_file.removeAllListeners();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    csv_file.on('close', function() {
        console.log("First: " + result); // Correct result here, executes first <-----
        callback(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't think you want to do `cntr++` when skipping over lines

Comment: You're right, that should have been ++cntr, accidentally modified that when making a shorter version of the code

Comment: Actually I meant you shouldn't increment `cntr` at all in the `name_search > name_array[cntr]` case, where you are not pushing a value into `result`. But maybe I just didn't understand your algorithm.

Comment: You do have to increment to the next search thing in the case that the line in the CSV file is alphabetically after the current search item (then try to see if the next search item is the same as that line before going to the next line in the CSV file, which would make it otherwise miss a possible match)